# Can't Upload Image In PHP Using The $_FILES Procedure

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I'm using PHP $_FILE procedure to upload an image to a specific folder, But nothing happens, I've tried using some snippets aswell but nothing seems to Work, I'm using PHP and JavaScript to do this,

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['postImage']))
    {
    $validextensions = array(
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
        "png",
        "gif"
    );
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["postImage"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);
    if ((($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.png") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.jpg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.jpeg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.gif")) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
        {
        if ($_FILES["postImage"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["postImage"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "<span>Your File Uploaded Succesfully...!!</span><br/>";
            echo "<br/><b>File Name:</b> " . $_FILES["postImage"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "<b>Type:</b> " . $_FILES["postImage"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "<b>Temp file:</b> " . $_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
            if (file_exists("../news/img/" . $_FILES["postImage"]["name"]))
                {
                echo $_FILES["postImage"]["name"] . " <b>already exists.</b> ";
                }
              else
                {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["postImage"]["tmp_name"], "../news/img/" . $_FILES["postImage"]["name"]);
                echo "<b>Stored in:</b> " . "../news/img/" . $_FILES["postImage"]["name"];
                }
            }
        }
      else
        {
        echo "<span>***Invalid file Size or Type***<span>";
        }
    }

?>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Function for Preview Image.
        $(function() {
        $(":file").change(function() {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
        });
        });
        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#message').css("display", "none");
        $('#preview').css("display", "block");
        $('#previewimg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        // Function for Deleting Preview Image.
        $("#deleteimg").click(function() {
        $('#preview').css("display", "none");
        $('#file').val("");
        });
        // Function for Displaying Details of Uploaded Image.
        $("#submit").click(function() {
        $('#preview').css("display", "none");
        $('#message').css("display", "block");
        });
        });
    </script>
```

the HTML code:

```
 <form action="" method="post">  
   <div id="message"></div>

   <input id="postImage" type="file" name="postImage" placeholder="Upload Image" value="">

   <input type="submit">

   <br>
   <br>

   <div id="preview">
      <img id="previewimg" src="">
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['postImage']))` that should be `$_FILES`; your conditional is based on that. Plus, you may need a valid enctype in your form.

Comment: You mean the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` right!

Comment: I've tried that already But doesnot work

Answer (score 2):

Change one line:

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You missed

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

for file upload.

Comment: Check image details using print_r($_FILES ). whether data coming or not.

Comment: that means your $_FILES doesn't have any value.

Comment: Sooo, how do I add value to It??? I've tried submiting It, BTW I'm using a live server.

Comment: put <input type="submit"/> code inside your <form> </form>. I think you miss that line.

Comment: @arqetech ........ $_POST & $_FILES only work when you submit form using submit buton or any other events.

Comment: The awesome Godaddy hosting

Comment: Note That: $_FILES don't have any value when you load it. It shows value when you submit it.

Comment: So Is there any other procedure to do It other than that?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
if (isset($_POST['postImage']))...
if ((($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.png") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.jpg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.jpeg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "../news/img/.gif")) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
```

To

```
if (isset($_FILE['postImage']))
if ((($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "png") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "jpg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == "jpeg") || ($_FILES["postImage"]["type"] == ".gif")) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions))
```

Comment: Error is in `if (isset($_FILE['postImage']))`

Comment: please note your errors... write your code into the if (isset($_FILES['postImage'])){}